# PL/SQL that show the name after insert

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have this table in my sqlplus

### Table

[Table teacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmJiT.png)

### What I want

I want a PL code that show "Inserted new teacher in the table profesor whose name is " and the name of the new teacher(atribute P in the database), for each row inserting in the database

### Example

INSERT INTO PROFESOR

VALUES('3030','JUANA',8,'CU');

**Inserted new teacher in the table profesor whose name is JUANA**

### Table Structure

I create the table wich this commands

CREATE TABLE PROFESOR

(DNI NUMBER(8) PRIMARY KEY,

P VARCHAR2(60),

CAR NUMBER(3),

CAT VARCHAR2(5));

Comment: where do you want to show this?

Comment: After the consult, Inserted new teacher in the table profesor whose name is, **The name of the teacher** . Like the example.

Comment: As I know triggers don't show anything